# Dynamically assign Javascript variables. [Getting rid of eval()]

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to improve a small framework, and therefore I want to get rid of two calls to `eval`.

Let the code speak:

```
# irf.coffee (The Framework)
# Classes which are appended to the namespace 'IRF'
classes = [
  "Background"
  "BoundingBox"
  # ...
]

# Namespace where to attach classes
@IRF = {}

# TODO: Get rid of eval(c)
for c in classes
  @IRF[c] = eval(c)
```

I only want the `IRF` to 'pollute' the global namespace so I could access classes/objects like `new IRF.Background()`.

The goal of this framework is to be used by other projects including this framework.
So I might have a project like this:

```
class TowerMap extends IRF.Game
  constructor: (width, height) ->
    @background = new IRF.Background(width, height)
```

As you see, I have to use the `IRF` namespace here, but within this particular project I'd like to use it without the namespace, as I did this:

```
# Require all Class of IRF, so we won't need namespace here
# TODO: get rid of eval
eval("var #{k} = v") for k,v of IRF

class TowerMap extends Game
  constructor: (width, height) ->
    @background = new Background(width, height)
```

Everything works as expected, but somehow those two `eval`s disturb me.
Might there be another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just import the bits you need?

```
Background = IRF.Background

class TowerMap extends Game
  constructor: (width, height) ->
    @background = new Background(width, height)
```

You should be aware that `eval` in EcmaScript 5 strict mode can't introduce new variable declarations so `eval('var x = ...')` in strict mode will not make a variable that is visible to surrounding non-eval code.

[EcmaScript 5 Appendix C](http://es5.github.com/#C) says

> Strict mode `eval` code cannot instantiate variables or functions in the variable environment of the caller to `eval`. Instead, a new variable environment is created and that environment is used for declaration binding instantiation for the `eval` code (10.4.2).

Comment: My first idea was to make it easy to require the framework, like `IRF.requireClasses()`. But did not get it to work, so did the eval as hacky implementation.

But I guess, it's best way to just require the bits I really use, instead of everything.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to access local variable by name from current context (at least, in ecmascript. Maybe coffeescript has some non-standard extension).

One can access only properties of some object. Global variables could be accessed as well, cause they are properties of global object; which is `window` in browsers' and could be obtained as `(function(){ return this })()` in ecma-3.